# 'mount' while using Cygwin

Tags: cygwin, mount

I'm trying to use the mount command to mount a directory from a computer here at work onto my Windows machine.

In cygwin, I've tried several variations:

```
mount machineName:/remote/location/blah /local/location
mount -t nfs machineName:/remote/location/blah /local/location
mount nfs machineName:/remote/location/blah /local/location
mount machineNAme:/remote/location/blah
```

AND I've tried it with the arguments switched around, etc. etc.... I either get this message :`mount: can't find brotula in /etc/fstab or in /etc/fstab.d/$USER` or `invalid arguments`. I know I have the paths right because I was using scp just fine.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried `$ mount //machinename/remote/location/blah /local/location` as per the examples in `man mount`?

Comment: The mount command succeeds but when I try to CD to it it says "not a directory". I'm using Windows XP and have Unix tools installed. Any idea why? It says `//192.168.1.2/media/sarnobat/Unsorted on /home/admin/u type unknown (binary,user)` in the mount output.

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat You're asking a follow up question, on SO you should open up a new question as this one has already been answered.