# Right way to mount nfs partition on windows using cygwin

Tags: linux, windows, cygwin, mount, nfs

I am trying to mount an nfs partition onto my Windows server 2012 which has cygwin running. I went through quite a few links, such as ['mount' while using Cygwin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10855758/mount-while-using-cygwin) but none have helped. I want to mount over nfs 10.x.x.x/foo into a partition on Windows, either inside c:/bar or to /tmp/bar.

On cygwin, I used the command:

```
mount //10.x.x.x/foo /tmp/bar
```

The mount command goes through, and the output of mount is:

```
$ mount 
//10.x.x.x/foo on /tmp/bar type unknown (binary,user) 
C:/cygwin/bin on /usr/bin type ntfs (binary,auto) 
C:/cygwin/lib on /usr/lib type ntfs (binary,auto) 
C:/cygwin on / type ntfs (binary,auto) 
C: on /cygdrive/c type ntfs (binary,posix=0,user,noumount,auto)
```

However, when I try to cd or ls into the directory, I do not see anything.

```
ls /tmp/bar 
ls: cannot access /tmp/bar: No such file or directory

$ ls -la /tmp/
ls: cannot access /tmp/vdnet: No such file or directory
total 4
drwxrwxrwt+ 1 Administrator None 0 Apr  5 10:34 .
drwxr-xr-x+ 1 Administrator None 0 Jul  9  2015 ..
d?????????? ? ?             ?    ?            ? bar
```

What is the right way to mount nfs partitions using cygwin?